# How to add junk JS files to cache using workbox in CRA - React/SW

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, offline-caching, workbox

I have added a custom SW file which I inject into the final SW file after-build step, and In this file, I'm using the below workbox configuration to cache files and it works fine as expected but I'm looking to add all of the junk files created by React lazy (split codes for every single route) before visiting them, I mean getting all of the js files (with their dynamic junk names which makes it hard to list them by hand and changing every time on build) in build directory and adding them into the cache.

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
   /\.(?:js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,
   new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({ // StaleWhileRevalidate get first from network and update cache, use cacher if network is not available; we can also use CacheFirst
      cacheName: "custom-assets-cache",
      plugins: [
         new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
            maxEntries: 2000,
            maxAgeSeconds: 7776000 // 3 months
         })
      ]
   })
);
```

If we had access to Node's FS, it was so easy to lest list of file names but as you know, we don't have access to FS on the front-end side.

Comment: Why not using precaching? Or making use of precache manifest?

Comment: actually yeah, I came across with precaching concept and I implemented it using google workbox 'injectManifest' .